# Is a boar hair beard brush permitted?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh

I've noticed the brushes for beard hair (and shaving to apply foam/gel if you decided to shave!) is made from boar (pig) hair. Can we use these?

Comment: In the city where you live, are all brushes made out of boar hair?

Comment: No but boar bristles appear to be the best; anyway I found on Amazon halal boar like bristles beard brush. Nevertheless according to https://islamqa.info/en/175729 after discussing the various opinions states the most correct opinion is that it is permissible to use boar bristle brushes so what do we make of this?

Comment: With only Maliki approving the use of boar hair (as per [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/ar/175729)), I would personally look for other alternatives unless this is my only option, albeit that they leaned toward it being permissible.